# Multi Layout Laravel & Vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

When i was using only laravel it was easy to make a site with 2 different designs for example an admin panel using AdminLte https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index.html
and main site using this design http://venoxis.epizy.com/project/

with blade it was easy I was making a folder for example called (admin) that has files (layout.blade.php, index.blade.php ..etc) all files inside that folder extends from **layout.blade.php**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('layouts.navbar');
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

so now i've the adminpanel layout ready and each page there has its own header (styles & title), scripts and content

now i'm using laravel and vuejs to make Single Page Application how can i do that?
i made **App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "App"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**App.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './components/App';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Dashboard from "./components/admin/Dashboard";

const routes = [
        {path: '/', component: ExampleComponent},
        {path:'/login', component: Login},
        {path:'/admin', component: Dashboard}
        ]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
});

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        App
    },
    router,
});
```

Comment: check this link https://itnext.io/anyway-heres-how-to-create-a-multiple-layout-system-with-vue-and-vue-router-b379baa91a05

Comment: @Evan that doesn't solve my problem.. how can i edit head data? how can i add more css files ?

in blade i could have done that
`<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    @yield('styles')
</head>`
so i can easily modify title and add my own styles per page

Comment: Hye @MiDo how did you solve that issue ?